# Shortcode to embed Edit Account form not working

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, forms, account

I'm creating a short code that shows both first and last name of the user if he's logged in, or, if he's logged in, but hasn't configured any name, it will return a random name with a message telling him to edit his profile.
I'm succeeding into getting the names, but not into showing the text that should appear in case the user has no name. The code:

```
// Show name if logged in - PT e ENG
function colaborador_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
          return '&nbsp;' .    $username = '<a href="' . ( admin_url('profile.php') .'">' . get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'first_name' , true) . '&nbsp;' .
        (($username = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'last_name', true)  . '</a>')  ? $username : '&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">Noe Name [edit profile]</a>"'));   
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborador_nome', 'colaborador_nome');
```

The part that's not working:

```
 ? $username : '&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">Noe Name [edit profile]</a>"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely did not understand how the code from my previous answer works, yeah? The PHP ternary operator `$result = $a ? $b : $c` works the same way as the following construction:

```php
if ( $a ) {
    $result = $b;
} else {
    $result = $c;
}
```

So the whole idea was to check if the `get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'last_name', true)` function returns an empty value. When you change it to

```
($username = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'last_name', true)  . '</a>') ? ...
```

you break the whole logic, because that

```
get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'last_name', true)  . '</a>'
```

string would never have an empty value (that should be quite obvious, even if the `get_user_meta()` function returns an empty value, the whole string would be equal to `'</a>'`). Use this statement:

```php
return '&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">' . ( ( $username = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_name', true ) ) ? $username : ">Noe Name [edit profile]" ) . '</a>';
```

**Update**

If you want to work with several user meta fields, I recommend to use [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) function:

```php
function colaborador_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
        $userdata = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
        $username = trim( implode( ' ', array( $userdata->first_name, $userdata->last_name ) ) );
        return '&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">' . ( $username ? $username : ">Noe Name [edit profile]" ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

I still don't understand why the shorthand form of ternary operator doesn't work for you, using it would help to simplify the `return` statement to

```php
return '&nbsp;<a href="' . admin_url('profile.php') . '">' . ( $username ?: ">Noe Name [edit profile]" ) . '</a>';
```

Comment: I was already able to achieve results by returning only one name, but I'm not able to do the same when I use both first and lastname.

Comment: @21321312 See the update.